# Keep sudo alive in Ruby script

Tags: ruby, shell

Is there a way to keep sudo alive in a Ruby script? I.e. I can ask a user to enter their sudo password once for the duration of a script?

In bash, you could do:

`while true; do sudo -n true; sleep 60; kill -0 "$$" || exit; done 2>/dev/null &`

Credit: [Cowboy](https://gist.github.com/cowboy/3118588)

Comment: Remember that every time you're executing a system command, you're doing so in a separate subshell. I guess that in a lot of cases, a script which requires elevated permissions would be run with sudo, e.g. `sudo script.rb`, rather than trying to do something within the script.

Comment: I strongly advise against this. This would mean a possible breach in security and there is a great chance of something going wrong. @TomFenech is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios, neither of which require you to do any in-program caching of credentials or authorization:

1. *The user can run arbitrary programs with `sudo`.*

   Just require your script to be run with `sudo` instead of calling `sudo` inside the script. Assume the worst, that your user is going to do that anyway.
2. *The user can only run certain programs with `sudo`.*

   In this case, the user can be assumed to be allowed to run the commands your script requires with `sudo`, but not your script itself. Either

   a) you can have the system administrator further configure `sudo` to allow the user to run those commands without a password, or

   b) the system administrator will *not* make that change, in which case you should not be circumventing that decision.

In any case, it is not your program's job to decide when or if a password is required for `sudo`.